# Laravel Quickadmin - User Role Redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel quickadmin to create an admin section
https://github.com/LaravelDaily/quickadmin

It allows to create roles and users based on roles. How can i redirect users of a specific role into website and not admin.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

change the following in the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() != null && $request->user()->permissionCan($request)) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    abort(403);
    return false;
}
```

to (alter "specific role" and "your route" as you wish)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() != null && $request->user()->permissionCan($request)) {
    $response = $next($request);

    if( $request->user()->role() == 'specific role'){
        redirect()->route('your route');
    }
    return $response;
    }
    abort(403);
    return false;
}
```